# Have 2 integers set as highest and 2nd highest numbers in vector

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 0; i < TRAVELCITIES; i++) {
    if ( closCityDist < distances[(depCity * 15) + i] && distances[(depCity * 15) + i] < 1 ){
        closCityDist = distances[(depCity * 15) + i];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < TRAVELCITIES; i++) {
    if (closCityDist < closeCity < distances[(depCity * 15) + i] && distances[(depCity * 15) + i] > 1) {
        closeCity = distances[(depCity * 15) + i];
    }
}

cout << "The two closest cities to " << cities[depCity] << " are " << closCityDist << " and " << closeCity << " miles away." << endl;
```

This is the part of my code im having trouble with. I need closCityDist to be set to the lowest value in the vector distances[] but higher then 0 and farCity to be set as the 2nd lowest value in the same vector.

1945  2838  1474  1064  0  1412  1335  1411  2773  2617  2532  942  1524  1640  2395

^ this is the part of the vector im using but I keep getting "The two closest cities to Denver are 0 and 2395 miles away." when I run it.
int closeCity and int closCityDist are equal to 0;

If I put something like cout << "test" << endl; in both if statements I only get an output for the bottom if statement.

I hope I explained this good enough. Any help is more then nothing.

Comment: When looking for the city closest to Denver **make sure you leave out Denver.**

Comment: In your snippet, I saw `closCityDist < closeCity < distances`. The compiler might not complain but this doesn't do what you might think.

Comment: Another "typo": `distances[(depCity * 15) + i] < 1`, you probably want `>` instead (and thresold should probably be 0 too).

Answer (score 1):

[`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort)
(or [range version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/partial_sort)) might be used:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(TRAVELCITIES);
std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0); // {0, 1, .., TRAVELCITIES-1}
auto distance_to_ref = [&](std::size_t index){ return distances[(depCity * 15) + index]; };

// std::partial_sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.begin() + 3, indexes.end(), [&](std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs){ return distance_to_ref(lhs) < distance_to_ref(rhs); });
std::ranges::partial_sort(indexes, indexes.begin() + 3, std::less{}, distance_to_ref);

// indexes[0] would be depCity (as distance would be 0 to itself)
std::cout << "The two closest cities to " << cities[depCity]
    << " are " << distance_to_ref(indexes[1])
    << " and " << distance_to_ref(indexes[2]) << " miles away." << std::endl;
```